# Iterating with multiple variables

Tags: python, string, variables

I am taking a course from Georgia Tech and I have spent all my evening trying to figure this out and I havent been able to do so. My task is as follows:

> Write a function called `my_TAs`. The function should take as
> input three strings: `first_TA`, `second_TA`, and `third_TA`. It
> should return as output the string, `"[first_TA], [second_TA],#and [third_TA] are awesome!"`, with the values replacing the
> variable names.
>
> For example, `my_TAs("Sridevi", "Lucy", "Xu")` would return
> the string `"Sridevi, Lucy, and Xu are awesome!"`.
>
> Hint: Notice that because you're returning a string instead
> of printing a string, you can't use the `print()` statement
> -- you'll have to create the string yourself, then return it.

My function returns `"Joshua are awesome"` instead of all three variables names. I tried this

```
result = str(first_TA), str(second_TA), str(third_TA) + "are awesome!"
```

but didn't work.

```
def my_TAs(first_TA, second_TA, third_TA):
    result = str(first_TA) + " are Awesome!"
    return result


first_TA = "Joshua"
second_TA = "Jackie"
third_TA = "Marguerite"


test_first_TA = "Joshua"
test_second_TA = "Jackie"
test_third_TA = "Marguerite"
print(my_TAs(test_first_TA, test_second_TA, test_third_TA))
```

Comment: Python uses + to combine strings not commas e.g. `first_TA + second_TA + third_TA + "are awesome!"`. I think you've confused the `print()` syntax of `print(s1,s2,s3)` with `s1+s2+s3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to accomplish this:

```
def my_TAs(first_TA, second_TA, third_TA):
    return f"{first_TA}, {second_TA}, and {third_TA} are awesome!"
    
test_first_TA = "Joshua"
test_second_TA = "Jackie"
test_third_TA = "Marguerite"
print(my_TAs(test_first_TA, test_second_TA, test_third_TA))
```

Output:

```
Joshua, Jackie, and Marguerite are awesome!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` instead of `,`

```
def my_TAs(first_TA, second_TA, third_TA):
        result = str(first_TA) + ", " + str(second_TA) +  ", and " + str(third_TA) 
+ " are Awesome!"
        return result
    
    
    first_TA = "Joshua"
    second_TA = "Jackie"
    third_TA = "Marguerite"
    
    
    test_first_TA = "Joshua"
    test_second_TA = "Jackie"
    test_third_TA = "Marguerite"
    print(my_TAs(test_first_TA, test_second_TA, test_third_TA))
```